# Converting UTF-8 to UTF-32, pre-calculating the number of 'chars' in each

Tags: c++, utf-8, string-conversion, utf-32

I have a working algorithm to convert a UTF-8 string to a UTF-32 string, however, I have to allocate all the space for my UTF-32 string ahead of time. Is there any way to know how many characters in UTF-32 that a UTF-8 string will take up.

For example, the UTF-8 string "¥0" is 3 chars, and once converted to UTF-32 is 2 unsigned ints. Is there any way to know the number of UTF-32 'chars' I will need before doing the conversion? Or am I going to have to re-write the algorithm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two basic options:

1. You could make two passes through the UTF-8 string, the first one counting the number of UTF-32 characters you'll need to generate, and the second one actually writing them to a buffer.
2. Allocate the max number of 32-bit chars you could possibly need -- i.e., the length of the UTF-8 string.  This is wasteful of memory, but means you can transform utf8->utf32 in one pass.

You could also use a hybrid -- e.g., if the string is shorter than some threshold then use the second approach, otherwise use the first.

For the first approach, the first pass would look something like this:

```
size_t len=0;  // warning: untested code.
for(const char *p=src; *p; ++p) {
    // characters that begin with binary 10xxxxxx... are continuations; all other
    // characters should begin a new utf32 char (assuming valid utf8 input)
    if ((*p & 0xc0) != 0x80) ++len;
}
```

Comment: +1, one comment: After option 2 you can `realloc` the UTF-32 array if it was allocated with `malloc` before. That way you don't waste memory, ideally.

Comment: @quinmars True.  Whether that's worth doing may depend on how long you intend to keep the utf32 string around for; if you'll be keeping it for a while, then it's worth trying to shrink it down.  If you're going to use it and then free it more quickly, then it may not be worth it.

Comment: I would tend to go with option #1 myself. It's a little more coding and a little more time to run, but it has the benefit of being able to let the first pass check the input to make sure it is valid UTF-8 while counting, before then allocating any memory for the second pass.

Comment: Don't you mean `if ((*p & 0xc0) != 0x80) ++len;`?

Comment: @masaers Yes I did.  Thanks for pointing this out -- I just fixed it.